# If I run multiple server with ASP.Net but store nothing in a session, do I need a state server?

Tags: asp.net, session-state

Is a state server required for handling postbacks from webforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you do not need a State Searver for handling postbacks... you can even disable Session Handling entirely in web.config if you don't use it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=VS.100).aspx

```
<system.web>
   <sessionState mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Any of the session state mechanisms (in-proc, state server or SqlServer) are only required if you are using session state.